# Specifying Qt Output Directory

Tags: file, qt, io, directory

In Qt in a Linux environment, how would I go about specifying that one file my application creates goes into a specific, hard-coded directory while another file created at the same time goes into a different hard-coded directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do but does this work?

```
QFile aFile("/some/hard/coded/path/filename");
QFile anotherFile("/another/hard/coded/path/filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about files other than MOC, obj, ui, rcc, and executable files, but you can specify where each of them go with the following:

```
Release:DESTDIR = release
Release:OBJECTS_DIR = release/.obj
Release:MOC_DIR = release/.moc
Release:RCC_DIR = release/.rcc
Release:UI_DIR = release/.ui

Debug:DESTDIR = debug
Debug:OBJECTS_DIR = debug/.obj
Debug:MOC_DIR = debug/.moc
Debug:RCC_DIR = debug/.rcc
Debug:UI_DIR = debug/.ui
```

If you want to set the output path for other files that are generated, I don't know if it is possible (you might need a custom build step, though I might be wrong)